# How to press block to bottom of main window?

Tags: javascript

There is a `div` block on the page with following CSS styles:

```
#block {
 position: fixed;
 height: 200px;
 width: 900px;
}
```

This block should be placed on the bottom of window even if window is scrolled.

My algorithm to achieve this purpose is:

1) Get scrolled distance from the top of page:

```
var w = window.scrollY
```

2) Get height of floating block `#block`:

```
   var hb = document.getElementById("block").offsetHeight
```

3) Get full height of window:

```
var hw = window.innerHeight
```

So, then I place float block to the bottom of window:

```
var startPlaceCoord = window.innerHeight - hb
```

Then if I scroll page down I increase `startPlaceCoord` to scrolled  distance from Y and vice versa:

```
startPlaceCoord = startPlaceCoord + w
```

But it does not work for me. Where I am wrong?

Comment: add **bottom: 0;** to your #block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `bottom:0` to your style declaration:

```
#block {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 200px;
 width: 900px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lucakiebel/ZsnuZ/2221/

Comment: You know if add bottom: 0 it works, but if I scroll page this block disappeared on bottom

Comment: No, it doesn't disappear, position: fixed keeps it from doing that

Comment: @OPV Give the scrolling page a bottom padding matching the height of the fixed block, e.g. 200px

Comment: What do you mean? You mean add margin-bottom on height of block

Comment: it does not work for me, may be set for parent container position: relTIVE?